# Protection Level to Objects in Form

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

I have this object in my form

When I went to build my solution, I got the following errors.

In MainForm.Designer.cs

```
public fCraft.ServerGUI.ConsoleBox console;

Error   1   'fCraft.ServerGUI.ConsoleBox' is inaccessible due to its protection level   C:\Users\JILL\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LegendCraft-master\ConfigGUI\MainForm.Designer.cs   4099    33  ConfigGUI

Error   2   Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'fCraft.ServerGUI.ConsoleBox' is less accessible than field 'fCraft.ConfigGUI.MainForm.console'  C:\Users\JILL\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LegendCraft-master\ConfigGUI\MainForm.Designer.cs   4099    44  ConfigGUI
```

Again again in MainForm.Designer.cs

```
this.console = new fCraft.ServerGUI.ConsoleBox();
Error   5   'fCraft.ServerGUI.ConsoleBox.ConsoleBox()' is inaccessible due to its protection level  C:\Users\JILL\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LegendCraft-master\ConfigGUI\MainForm.Designer.cs   312 28  ConfigGUI
```

How am I supposed to fix this error so that I may release my program?

Comment: can you post your code source   please

Comment: meaning what is in MainForm.cs?

Comment: we need all classes without method's body  as we need to  understand the modifiers level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ConsoleBox class needs to be declared public to be used in another assembly.